# fixing a randomly generated number in a session

Tags: php

Sorry to bother people with this. I have searched for an answer everywhere without success, although I accept that I am a complete newbie. Is there anyway in PHP to generate a random number 1-100 that you can then 'fix' i.e. keep it constant so it can be used in different ways in a session. I have a hundred photos in an application which I wish to display by selecting one at random and then displaying the next 20. As I loop through the code, the mt_rand function regenerates another number and another and so on and every now and then it means that photos shown are duplicated....i.e. it has no knowledge of the random numbers it has previously shown in that session. Can't seem to fix it in the $_SESSION superglobal. Again apologies....don't know if you offer help on these kinds of matters.

Comment: You should include the code that you've written in your question; it'll help people point you in the right direction.

Comment: You could create an array that stores each random number generated. Store this array as a $_SESSION variable. Once you generate the random number again, check to see if that number exists within the array, if it does, regenerate another number and check again.

Comment: or create a session array of numbers 1 to 100 and randomise it. Then cycle through them. You could also regenerate it at the end or return to the start again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session_start(); // start a session

if(!isset($_SESSION['startNum']))
    $_SESSION['startNum'] = rand(1,100); // if not set define a new number between 1 and 100

for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    echo '<img id="'.$_SESSION['startNum']+$i.'">';
```

Comment: thanks a million for this - it worked really well. Most importantly i was able to compare this to what i had done and see what i was doing wrong which is golden. Again, thank you Yotam and Jeff....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to you `$_SESSION` superglobal variables:

### PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['index']))
        $_SESSION['index'] = rand(1,100);
    
    #It won't generate a new number if the variable is already set.
    #You can then loop

    $max = $_SESSION['index']+20;

    while($_SESSION['index']<$max)
    {
        /* Here we echo the necessary code for each image we loop to */
        echo "<img src=".$myImgArray[$_SESSION['index']]['src']."/>";

        /* We increment the index until it reaches its original value + 20 */
        $_SESSION['index'] +=1;
    }
?>
```